# Is there a program for managing glossary tags?

Tags: glossaries, jabref

> **This question led to a new application:**
>   [`bib2gls`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls)

I use the "glossaries" package a lot, and it is *super* helpful in complex writing for sorting lots of things out. However, as my "glossary.tex" file gets larger and larger, it becomes more difficult to manage. I was hoping to find a program for that task, similar to JabRef, but I can't.

Does anyone know of one? A program that could be adapted for the same purpose would also be appreciated.

Comment: You could use [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/), and put the items into a simple database. You can then export the items you need using either the SQL-editor for _ad hoc_ queries or making report forms.

Comment: @Sveinung That's a good solution if you're starting from scratch. generate a database and export it into a report that would generate the tex. Here, however, we need some sort of software that will be able to read an existing tex file and manage it

Comment: looks like there isn't such a software... Jabref is open source, could one use Jabref and tweek its feilds to read a tex glossaries files ? would that be legal under the gnu license ?

Comment: Which licence is it? But legality is strictly off-topic @EladDen.

Comment: JabRef recently switched to the MIT license. @EladDen Tweaking JabRef would definitely be legal. I am new to the glossaries package, but the information stored in them looks structurally similar to BibTeX entries (a key and several field-value pairs). So I think you could store this information in JabRef. What you would need is an importer and an exporter that translates the tex code of a glossary entry into / from a BibTeX entry. If you feel like it, you could propose the feature at http://discourse.jabref.org/ and motivate it a little.

Comment: I am one of the JabRef devs, too. It would be nice if you coud explain this in more detail.

Comment: @ChristophS A late welcome to the site. Always nice to see you guys here.

Comment: I did think about writing one, but I have too many other projects to find the time. If it is possible to tweak JabRef, some things to take into account: there are fields that by default derive their value from other fields (e.g. `text` defaults to the same value as `name`, `plural` defaults to `text` with `s` appended); it's possible to add custom fields, so there isn't a fixed set of fields (e.g. `glossaries-accsup.sty`, `glossaries-prefix.sty` and `glossaries-extra.sty` add extra fields); the `type` field may need changing according to the document; abbreviations may need different handling.

Comment: @ChristophS thanks for looking into this ! Jabref knows how to load(and save) *.bib files, and read the entries in them, then display a GUI that allows you to manage the entries as well as edit them and add new entries to your file. What we seek in this thread is a GUI software that will load a *.tex file that contains acronyms and glossary entries, and manage them in a similar way. You can see the definitions of entries in a glossaries file [here](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf).

Comment: I was thinking one could replace the fields of the bibtex (author, title, etc.) with the fields of the glossay definition (name, description, sort, ect.). Also, there would have to be a way to differentiate between acronym and glossary, this can be done in the same way bibtex differentiates between `@misc` and `@article` for instance.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot thanks for the input, and more than that - thanks for this awesome package.

Comment: As JabRef already supports managing journal abbreviations and protected terms, I think  this could be done in a similar manner, by using the glossaries file as input. I will try to come up with a solution. It would also be nice if you could provide me some sample entries, for testing.

Comment: Does anybody know if it would be possible to write a Biblatex style to produce a glossary? Right now, this would not be very usable because of difficulties combining different styles in a single document (esp. re. sort order), but hopefully that will eventually change ... Or to use Biber to do the generation with some independent package? `glossaries` doesn't work anywhere near as smoothly as I'd like and requires a lot of manual attention in my case, which makes it prone to error. This isn't a criticism: it is just not great for the glossaries I need to make.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As there currently does not exist such tool and it seems many users want to have such a tool, I decided to integrate this into JabRef as a feature.
The idea is to have a similar, but more advanced functionality like for managing journal abbrevations in JabRef.

Therefore I have created an issue to track the development. 
https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/2366

I will probably start around Christmas with the development.

Answer (score 11):

(Answer rewritten following release of `bib2gls` v1.0.)

There's a new command line application called [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) that can be used to convert `.bib` files to a format that can be input using `glossaries-extra`'s `\GlsXtrLoadResources` command. The `record` package option is required. The application requires at least Java 7, although newer versions are recommended (Java 7 has reached its end of life and is now deprecated). It also needs at least v1.12 of [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra), but works better with the latest version.

The application performs two functions in one:

1. fetches the information from the `.bib` file(s) according to the information found in the `.aux` file (like `bibtex`);
2. performs hierarchical sorting and collates locations (like `makeindex` or `xindy`).

This means you can use JabRef to manage the entries. Unlike `makeindex`, `xindy` and `bibtex`, the file created by `bib2gls` isn't the formatted list but the entry definitions provided in the order obtained from sorting. Only those entries that were selected from the `.bib` file are defined and since they have been defined in the appropriate order, the glossary can simply be displayed using `\printunsrtglossary` (or `\printunsrtglossaries`), which is provided by `glossaries-extra`.

The `record` package option automatically switches on `undefaction=warn`, which means that if you try to reference (with `\gls` etc) an undefined entry then you just get a warning instead of an error. On the first LaTeX run the entries aren't defined (as with `\cite`). This means that iterative commands like `\glsaddall` don't work. Instead you can use `selection=all` in the options of `\GlsXtrLoadResources`.

If you already have existing `.tex` files containing all your entry definitions (that's loaded with `\input` or `\loadglsentries`) then you can use the supplementary application `convertgls2bib` to convert it to a `.bib` file for use with `bib2gls`. For example, suppose `entries.tex` contains:

```
\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\newabbreviation{html}{HTML}{Hypertext Markup Language}

\newterm[plural=geese]{goose}

\newterm[see={[\seealsoname]goose}]{duck}
```

then

```
convertgls2bib entries.tex entries.bib
```

will create the file `entries.bib` that contains:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
@entry{sample,
  name = {sample},
  description = {an example}
}

@abbreviation{html,
  short = {HTML},
  long = {Hypertext Markup Language}
}

@index{goose,
  plural = {geese}
}

@index{duck,
  seealso = {goose}
}
```

The `.bib` encoding can be changed using `--bibenc` <*encoding*> and the `.tex` encoding can be specified using `--texenc` <*encoding*>. For example:

```
convertgls2bib --texenc UTF-8 --bibenc UTF-8 entries.tex entries.bib
```

The `.bib` format doesn't permit spaces in labels so you can use `--space-sub` <*replacement*> to replace spaces with <*replacement*>. For example:

```
convertgls2bib --space-sub '-' entries.tex entries.bib
```

or

```
convertgls2bib --space-sub '' entries.tex entries.bib
```

Remember that you'll need to make the relevant changes in your `\gls` etc argument to reflect this substitution.

`bib2gls` has a primitive LaTeX interpreter to allow it to deduce the `sort` value if omitted. If you use `@preamble` to provide commands, `bib2gls` will try to add them to the interpreter's list of known commands. You can store the `@preamble` code in separate `.bib` files if the provided commands are used in entries defined in multiple `.bib` files. It may be that you don't want the interpreter to pick up some command definitions, so you could divide the `@preamble` up into two files, say `glossdefs-interpret.bib` and `glossdefs-nointerpret.bib`.

For example, suppose I need:

```
\providecommand{\strong}[1]{\textbf{\color{red}#1}}
\providecommand{\swap}[2]{#2 (#1)}
```

and suppose I start with just one `.bib` file called `entries.bib`:

```
@preamble{"\providecommand{\strong}[1]{\textbf{\color{red}#1}}
\providecommand{\swap}[2]{#2 (#1)}"}

@index{example,
  name={\strong{\swap{stuff}{example}}}
}

@index{sample}
@index{test}
@index{foo}
@index{bar}
```

Here's the test document `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[record,style=indexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries},selection=all]

% adjust indexgroup style:
\renewcommand{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\glstreegroupheaderfmt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

The build process is:

```
pdflatex test
bib2gls --group test
pdflatex test
```

(The `--group` switch is needed because I'm using a glossary style that has letter groups.) The result looks like:

[image: Glossary B bar F foo R example (stuff) S sample T test]

Inspecting `test.glstex` (the file created by `bib2gls`) shows that the `sort` value for `example` is

```
sort={redexample (stuff)}
```

This is because `bib2gls` has picked up the definitions of both `\strong` and `\swap` from `@preamble`, so it expands

```
\strong{\test{stuff}{example}
```

to

```
\textbf{\color{red}example (stuff)}
```

and then ignores `\textbf` and `\color` leaving `redexample (stuff)`, which is why the `example` entry ends up in the R letter group.

I can use `interpret-preamble=false` to prevent `bib2gls` from trying to interpret the contents of `@preamble` (it will just write the contents to the `.glstex` file):

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={entries},% definitions are in entries.bib
  selection=all,% select all entries
  interpret-preamble=false% don't interpret @preamble
```

]

Now the document looks like:

[image: Glossary B bar F foo S sample example (stuff) T test]

Inspecting the `.glstex` file shows that the `sort` value for `example` has been set as:

```
sort={stuffexample}
```

This is because `bib2gls` now doesn't recognise `\strong` or `\swap` so it interprets `\strong{\test{stuff}{example}}` as simply `stuffexample`, which is why `example` now ends up in the S letter group. What's needed is for `bib2gls` to pick up the definition of `\swap` but not `\strong`, so I need to create the file `glossdefs-nointerpret.bib` that contains:

```
@preamble{"\providecommand{\strong}[1]{\textbf{\color{red}#1}}"}
```

and  `glossdefs-interpret.bib` that contains:

```
@preamble{"\providecommand{\swap}[2]{#2 (#1)}"}
```

The document is now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[record,style=indexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={glossdefs-nointerpret},interpret-preamble=false]
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={glossdefs-interpret,entries},selection=all]

% adjust indexgroup style:
\renewcommand{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\glstreegroupheaderfmt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

which now results in:

[image: Glossary B bar E example (stuff) F foo S sample T test]

You can have multiple `\GlsXtrLoadResources`. Any definitions found in `@preamble` will be remembered for the next resource set so the above can also be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[record,style=indexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={glossdefs-nointerpret},interpret-preamble=false]
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={glossdefs-interpret}]
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries},selection=all]

% adjust indexgroup style:
\renewcommand{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\glstreegroupheaderfmt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

You can have multiple `.bib` files listed in `src`, in which case they'll all be sorted together. Each `\GlsXtrResources` set is sorted independently of the other sets. Suppose `testfile1.bib` contains:

```
@index{duck}
@index{zebra}
@index{aardvark}
```

and `testfile2.bib` contains:

```
@index{caterpillar}
@index{bee}
@index{wombat}
```

and `test.tex` contains:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record,style=indexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={testfile1,testfile2},selection=all]

% adjust indexgroup style:
\renewcommand{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\glstreegroupheaderfmt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

then the result is

[image: Glossary A aardvark B bee C caterpillar D duck W wombat Z zebra]

However, if I load the `.bib` files using two separate resource commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record,style=indexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={testfile1},selection=all]
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={testfile2},selection=all]

% adjust indexgroup style:
\renewcommand{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\glstreegroupheaderfmt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

then the result is a bit weird:

[image: Glossary A aardvark D duck Z zebra B bee C caterpillar W wombat]

but I can make use of this to alter the normal letter grouping:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record,style=indexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={testfile1},
 group={Group 1},
 selection=all]
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={testfile2},
 sort={letter-nocase-reverse},
 group={Group 2},
 selection=all]

% adjust indexgroup style:
\renewcommand{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\glstreegroupheaderfmt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

(For illustrative purposes, I've sorted the second set differently.) This produces:

[image: Glossary Group 1 aardvark duck zebra Group 2 wombat caterpillar bee]

If you have any abbreviations you need to set the abbreviation style before the resource command. For example, suppose `entries-abbrv.bib` contains:

```
@string{ssi={server-side includes}}
@string{html={hypertext markup language}}

@abbreviation{shtml,
  short="shtml",
  long= ssi # " enabled " # html,
  description={a combination of \gls{html} and \gls{ssi}},
  seealso={html,ssi}
}

@abbreviation{html,
  short ="html",
  long  = html,
  description={a markup language for creating web pages}
}

@abbreviation{ssi,
  short="ssi",
  long = ssi,
  description={a simple interpreted server-side scripting language}
}
```

and `test.tex` contains:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[record,style=indexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-sc-desc}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries-abbrv}]

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{shtml}. Next use: \gls{shtml}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

Note that although `shtml` has been used in the document, the dependent entries `html` and `ssi` are automatically selected. The build process is still:

```
pdflatex test
bib2gls --group test
pdflatex test
```

This is different to `makeglossaries` which requires an extra `makeglossaries` and `pdflatex` to index the dependents. However the corresponding locations aren't picked up until a subsequent `bib2gls` and `pdflatex` call. Then the result looks like:

[image: image of document]

I can suppress the indexing in the glossary by changing the format to `glsignore`, which `bib2gls` recognises as a special ignored location:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[record,style=indexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-sc-desc}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries-abbrv}]

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{shtml}. Next use: \gls{shtml}.

\GlsXtrSetDefaultNumberFormat{glsignore}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

If I want to use the `long-short-sc` style instead I can tell `bib2gls` to ignore the `description` field provided in the `.bib` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[record,style=indexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-sc}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries-abbrv},
   ignore-fields={description}]

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{shtml}. Next use: \gls{shtml}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

If I change my mind and decide I actually want normal upper case short forms instead of using `\textsc` I can tell `bib2gls` to change the case of the `short` field:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[record,style=indexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries-abbrv},
   short-case-change={uc},
   ignore-fields={description}]

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{shtml}. Next use: \gls{shtml}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

Now let's suppose I've been using the `\newdualentry` example command described in the `glossaries` manual. The closest matching entry type is `@dualentryabbreviation`, so I'm going to change `entries-abbrv.bib` to use that instead of `@abbreviation`:

```
@string{ssi={server-side includes}}
@string{html={hypertext markup language}}

@dualentryabbreviation{shtml,
  short="shtml",
  long= ssi # " enabled " # html,
  description={a combination of \gls{html} and \gls{ssi}},
  seealso={html,ssi}
}

@dualentryabbreviation{html,
  short ="html",
  long  = html,
  description={a markup language for creating web pages}
}

@dualentryabbreviation{ssi,
  short="ssi",
  long = ssi,
  description={a simple interpreted server-side scripting language}
}
```

The document needs the `abbreviations` package option, otherwise all the terms and abbreviations will end up in the `main` glossary:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[record,abbreviations,style=indexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-sc}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries-abbrv}]

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{shtml}. Next use: \gls{shtml}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

Here's an example of a hierarchical index. The file `entries.bib` contains:

```
@index{birds}
@index{duck,parent={birds}}
@index{goose,plural={geese},parent={birds}}
@index{swan,parent={birds}}
@index{chicken,parent={birds}}

@index{vegetable}
@index{cabbage,parent={vegetable}}

@index{minerals}
@index{quartz,parent={minerals}}
@index{corundum,parent={minerals}}
@index{amber,parent={minerals}}
@index{gypsum,parent={minerals}}

@index{aardvark}
@index{bard}
@index{buzz}

@index{item}
@index{subitem,parent={item}}
@index{subsubitem,parent={subitem}}

@index{parentid,name={parent name}}
@entry{child,parent={parentid},description={an example}}
```

The file `test.tex` contains:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record,stylemods={mcols},style=mcolindexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries.bib}]

% adjust mcolindexgroup style:
\renewcommand{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\glstreegroupheaderfmt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\gls{duck}.

\gls{quartz}, \gls{corundum}, \gls{amber}.

\gls{aardvark}, \gls{bard}, \gls{buzz}.

\gls{vegetable}, \gls{cabbage}.

\gls{subsubitem}.

\gls{child}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

The resulting document looks like:

[image: image of document]

The duck's siblings haven't been selected, so the duck entry looks a little lonely. We can neaten the list by flattening the duck, which involves adjusting the `name`, `text` and `parent` to shift it up one hierarchical level. The parent `bird` entry is then no longer required and can be removed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record,stylemods={mcols},style=mcolindexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries.bib},
 flatten-lonely=postsort% flatten lonely children
]

% adjust mcolindexgroup style:
\renewcommand{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\glstreegroupheaderfmt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\gls{duck}.

\gls{quartz}, \gls{corundum}, \gls{amber}.

\gls{aardvark}, \gls{bard}, \gls{buzz}.

\gls{vegetable}, \gls{cabbage}.

\gls{subsubitem}.

\gls{child}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

This now produces:

[image: image of document]

The duck has now been flattened but not the cabbage. This is because the parent entry (vegetable) has been indexed in the document, so it can't be removed. The cabbage can be flattened by changing the flatten lonely rule but its parent still can't be removed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record,stylemods={mcols},style=mcolindexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries.bib},
 flatten-lonely=postsort,% flatten lonely children
 flatten-lonely-rule=discard unrecorded
]

% adjust mcolindexgroup style:
\renewcommand{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\glstreegroupheaderfmt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\gls{duck}.

\gls{quartz}, \gls{corundum}, \gls{amber}.

\gls{aardvark}, \gls{bard}, \gls{buzz}.

\gls{vegetable}, \gls{cabbage}.

\gls{subsubitem}.

\gls{child}.

\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: image of document]

The `bib2gls` user manual contains a full description of all entry types, but here's a summary:

- `@entry` required fields: `description` and `name` or `parent`. If `name` is omitted it's obtained from the parent name. If `sort` is omitted it's obtained from `name`.
- `@symbol` required fields: `name` or `parent`. If `name` is omitted `description` is also required and the `name` is obtained from the parent name. If `sort` is omitted it's obtained from the entry's *label*.
- `@number` as `@symbol`
- `@index` no required fields. If `name` is omitted it's taken from the entry's *label*. If `sort` is omitted it's obtained from the `name`.
- `@abbreviation` required fields: `long` and `short`. If `sort` is omitted it's taken from the `short` field.
- `@acronym` as `@abbreviation`
- `@dualentry` required fields: `name` and `description`. If `sort` is omitted it's taken from `name`. This also creates a corresponding entry with the label `dual.`*label* that has the `name` and `description` flipped.
- `@dualentryabbreviation` required fields: `short`, `long`, `description`. The primary entry is an abbreviation (sorted according to `short`) and the dual entry is a regular term (sorted according to `long`).
- `@dualsymbol` required fields: `name` and `symbol`.  This creates a corresponding entry with the label `dual.`*label* that has the `name` and `symbol` flipped.
- `@dualnumber` as `@dualsymbol`
- `@dualabbreviation` required fields: `short`, `long`, `dualshort` and `duallong`.   This creates a corresponding abbreviation with the label `dual.`*label* that has the `short` and `dualshort` flipped and `long` and `duallong` flipped.
- `@dualacronym` as `@dualabbreviation`

The base `glossaries` package provides the fields: `name`, `description`, `parent`, `descriptionplural`, `text`, `first`, `plural`, `firstplural`, `symbol`, `symbolplural`, `sort`, `type`, `user1`, `user2`, `user3`, `user4`, `user5`, `user6`, `nonumberlist`, `see`, `short`, `shortplural`, `long` and `longplural` and (if `\makenoidxglossaries`) `loclist`.

For the `.bib` file it's best to avoid `sort`, `type` and `nonumberlist`. There's greater flexibility with the `\GlsXtrLoadResources` options. Don't set `loclist` as it's a private field with its own custom format.

The extension package provides additional fields: `category`, `alias`, `seealso` and (if the `record` option is used) `group`.

In addition `bib2gls` recognises the fields: `dualshort`, `dualshortplural`, `duallong`, `duallongplural`, `dualplural`. It also provides fields for its own private use (so don't use these in the `bib` file, but you can access them in the document when provided): `location`, `dual`, `childcount`.

The `glossaries-accsupp` package (`\usepackage[accsupp]{glossaries-extra}`) provides: `access`, `textaccess`, `firstaccess`, `pluralaccess`, `firstpluralaccess`, `symbolaccess`, `symbolpluralaccess`, `descriptionaccess`, `descriptionpluralaccess`, `longaccess`, `shortaccess`, `longpluralaccess`, `shortpluralaccess`.

The `glossaries-prefix` package provides: `prefix`, `prefixplural`, `prefixfirst` and `prefixfirstplural`.

If you provide your own fields using commands like `\glsaddkey`, put the definition before the first instance of `\GlsXtrLoadResources`.

Comment: The bib file works fine with JabRef and it already loads all the fields and shows them for editing. Of course it shows the standard fields, too.  It would be nice if you could add some metadata in the comment field, e.g. `@Comment{xxx-meta: glossaries-v1}`
If you need any futher help, just ask me.

Comment: @ChristophS Thanks for checking. That's great. Is there a reference for the `@Comment` syntax? (`bib2gls` picks up all the fields defined in the document from the `.aux` file, so it knows which ones to select from that. It will ignore unknown fields.)

Comment: There is no real documentation about the `@Comment` field. [Some defintion here](http://maverick.inria.fr/~Xavier.Decoret/resources/xdkbibtex/bibtex_summary.html#comment).  
In JabRef we use it to store information about the format (bibtex/biblatex) `@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:biblatex;}`.  
We also store information about the groups defintion/tree in several Comment fields.  
From a JabRef point of view it would help to have just some simple metadata, to indicate that this is a (valid) glossary-bib file. Then we could show/hide some irrelevant fields/add new.

Comment: @ChristophS Okay, so perhaps something like `@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bib2gls;}` which would by show the default set of fields. (I'll add the list of known fields to my answer.)

Answer (score 5):

I'm posting this answer since all this information is hard to fit in a comment.

To sum up the comments: It seems such software does not exist. It should either be developed, or an existing bibtex managing software, such as Jabref, can be tweaked to handle *.tex files containing glossaries definitions. @Christoph S of the Jabref dev team has shown his willingness to hear more, so here's a brief explanation:

The glossaries file has a somewhat resemblence to a bib file, where instead of bibliographical entries, the glossaries *.tex file contains glossaries entries.
The definitions of glossaries (that can replace the entry type in bibtex, i.e. @misc) are:

```
\newglossaryentry
\longnewglossaryentry
\newacronym
\newterm
\newabbrevation
\glsxtrnewsymbol
\glsxtrnewnumber
```

The fields that a glossary entry can have are

```
name
description
parent
descriptionplural
text
first
plural
firstplural
symbol
symbolplural
sort
type
user1,...,user6
nonumberlist
see
```

A glossary managing GUI would have to be able to read these fields, manage entries and produce new ones.

Here is a glossaries sample file compiled from several sample files provided by the glossaries package

```
% This is a sample file, it was produced from the glossaries package sample files.


% The following definition of glossaries are typical and are used by most users, 
% they are covered by the beginners guide, and are simple

\newglossaryentry{Perl}{name=\texttt{Perl},
    sort=Perl, % need a sort key because name contains a command
    description=A scripting language}

\newglossaryentry{glossary}{name=glossary,
    description={\nopostdesc},
    plural={glossaries}}

\newglossaryentry{glossarycol}{
    description={collection of glosses},
    sort={2},
    parent={glossary}}

\newglossaryentry{glossarylist}{
    description={list of technical words},
    sort={1},
    parent={glossary}}

\newglossaryentry{pagelist}{name=page list,
    % description value has to be enclosed in braces
    % because it contains commas
    description={a list of individual pages or page ranges
        (e.g.\ 1,2,4,7-9)}}

\newglossaryentry{mtrx}{name=matrix,
    description={rectangular array of quantities},
    % plural is not simply obtained by appending an s, so specify
    plural=matrices}

% entry with a paragraph break in the description

\newglossaryentry{par}{name=paragraph,
    description={distinct section of piece of
        writing.\glspar Beginning on new, usually indented, line}}

% entry with two types of plural. Set the plural form to the
% form most likely to be used. If you want to use a different
% plural, you will need to explicity specify it in \glslink
\newglossaryentry{cow}{name=cow,
    % this isn't necessary, as this form (appending an s) is
    % the default
    plural=cows,
    % description:
    description={(\emph{pl.}\ cows, \emph{archaic} kine) an adult
        female of any bovine animal}}

\newglossaryentry{bravo}{name={bravo},
    description={\nopostdesc}}

\newglossaryentry{bravo1}{description={cry of approval (pl.\ bravos)},
    sort={1},
    plural={bravos},
    parent=bravo}

\newglossaryentry{bravo2}{description={hired ruffian or killer (pl.\ bravoes)},
    sort={2},
    plural={bravoes},
    parent=bravo}

\newglossaryentry{seal}{%
    name=seal,%
    description={sea mammal with flippers that eats fish}
}

\newglossaryentry{sealion}{%
    name={sea lion},%
    description={large seal}%
}

\newglossaryentry{M}{name={$M$},
    sort=M,
    description={mass},
    symbol=kg}

\newglossaryentry{svm}{
    % how the entry name should appear in the glossary
    name={Support vector machine (SVM)},
    % how the description should appear in the glossary
    description={Statistical pattern recognition
        technique~\cite{svm}},
    % how the entry should appear in the document text
    text={svm},
    % how the entry should appear the first time it is
    % used in the document text
    first={support vector machine (svm)}}

\newglossaryentry{ksvm}{
    name={Kernel support vector machine (KSVM)},
    description={Statistical pattern recognition technique
        using the ``kernel trick'' (see also SVM)},
    text={ksvm},
    first={kernel support vector machine}}

\newglossaryentry{ident}{name=identity matrix,
    description=diagonal matrix with 1s along the leading diagonal,
    plural=identity matrices}


% These are special characters or protected characters. glossaries knows how to handle these.
\newglossaryentry{quote}{name={"},
    description={the double quote symbol}}

\newglossaryentry{at}{name={@},
    description={the ``at'' symbol}}

\newglossaryentry{excl}{name={!},
    description={the exclamation mark symbol}}

\newglossaryentry{bar}{name={\ensuremath{|}},
    description={the vertical bar symbol}}

\newglossaryentry{hash}{name={\#},
    description={the hash symbol}}

\newglossaryentry{emigre}{%
    name={{é}migré},
    description={person who has emigrated to another country,
        especially for political reasons}
}

\newglossaryentry{not:set}{type=notation, % glossary type
    name={$\mathcal{S}$},
    description={A set},
    sort={S}}

%If one wants to use \gls call in a formula, he'd used the \ensuremath command
\newglossaryentry{Gamma}{name=\ensuremath{\Gamma(z)},
    description=Gamma function,
    sort=Gamma}

\newglossaryentry{Phi}{name={\ensuremath{\Phi(\alpha,\gamma;z)}},
    description=confluent hypergeometric function,sort=Pagz}

\newglossaryentry{knu}{name=\ensuremath{k_\nu(x)},
    description=Bateman's function,sort=kv}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% typical acronym definitions

%the typical definition of an acronym is this, that is not quite similar to the name={field}... This could pose a challange for tweaking a program such as jabref...

\newacronym{svm1}% label
{svm1}% abbreviation
{support vector machine one}% long form

\newacronym{laser}{laser}{light amplification by stimulated
    emission of radiation}





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% These are samples I found in the samples provided by the glossaries package.
%%% They are more complex and are covered in the long detailed users guide
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\longnewglossaryentry{par1}{name={par1}}%
{%
    A long description with a paragraph break.

    This is the next paragraph.


% non-standard definition of an acronym - never used anything like that either
% This contrived acronym has non-standard plural forms.
% These are specified in the optional argument.
% Remove the optional argument to revert to the default
% plurals.
\newacronym[\glsshortpluralkey=cas,\glslongpluralkey=contrived
acronyms]{aca}{aca}{a contrived acronym}

\newacronym[description={a device that emits a narrow beam of
    light}]{laser}{laser}{light amplification by stimulated
    emission of radiation}

\newacronym[shortaccess=S V M]{svm}{svm}{support vector machine}

\newacronym[type=main]{vc}{VC}{Vector Calculus}

\newglossaryentry{pear}{name=pear,
    description={an oddly shaped fruit}}

\newglossaryentry{apple}{name=apple,
    description={firm, round fruit},
    see=[see also]{pear}}

\newglossaryentry{banana}{name=banana,
    description={a yellow fruit with an even odder shape than
        a \gls{pear}}}

\newglossaryentry{fruit}{name=fruit,
    description={sweet, fleshy product of plant containing seed}}

\glssee{fruit}{pear,apple,banana}

\newabbr{eg}{e.g.}{exempli gratia}
\newabbr{ie}{i.e.}{id est}
\newabbr{bsc}{B.Sc.}{Bachelor of Science}

\newdualentry{svm}% label
{SVM}% abbreviation
{support vector machine}% long form
{Statistical pattern recognition technique}% description

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},
    description={an example},
    prefix={a~},
    prefixplural={the\space}%
}

\newglossaryentry{oeil}{name={oeil},
    plural={yeux},
    description={eye},
    prefix={l'},
    prefixplural={les\space}}


%these are samples with custome fields (or keys), that is ed and ing are defined in the preamble of tex file and then these are defined. I would not expect a managing program to have a preamble for custom definitions, however, being able to produce custom 
\newglossaryentry{run}{name={run},%
    ed={ran},%
    ing={running},
    description={}}

\newglossaryentry{waddle}{name={waddle},%
    ed={waddled},%
    ing={waddling},%
    description={}}
```

The greatest challange that I see is the definition of a new acronym: It does not adhere to the typical structure of entry definition in bibtex.

as to @Nicola Talbot's concern with custom fields, Jabref has an option of editing an entry bib source, there one could add a custom bib field, the same can be done in the glossaries.

Comment: There's also [`\newterm`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/sample-index.tex) provided by `\usepackage[index]{glossaries}` as well as [`\newabbreviation`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/sample-mixed-abbrv-styles.tex), `\glsxtrnewsymbol` and `\glsxtrnewnumber` provided by `glossaries-extra.sty`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot thanks ! do they have the same keys or do these define new ones ?

Comment: `\newacronym` and `\newabbreviation` set `long`, `longplural`, `short` and `shortplural` (to the long and short forms) and the `type` field (to `\acronymtype` and `\glsxtrabbrvtype`, respectively). With `glossaries-extra` all of those commands also set the `category` field. Those commands have an optional argument that can be used to set (or override) any of the fields available with `\newglossaryentry`. So perhaps if the `long` and `short` fields are set, it could identify an entry as an abbreviation and the export could then write them as either `\newacronym` or `\newabbreviation`.

Comment: Thank you both for the brief information. I have created an issue for me to track the progress and will start working on it.  I already have some ideas how to handle it technically https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/2366

Comment: The Gloss package by Bezos and Diaz already uses BibTeX as a database to handle large glossaries as entries.

Answer (score 2):

With the [gloss](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gloss) package by Bezos and Diaz you may manage glossaries as bibliographies with BibTeX; you use the `\gloss` command instead of `\cite`, and I guess JabRef without modification. Documentation is pretty clear. So I believe that what the OP asks for already exists.

Comment: This looks like an awesome tool, however, the `glossaries` package has many advantages: acronyms, styles and the long form being shown when first called are just a few.
The glossaries package is widely used, and therefore a tool for managing `glossaries` database is required, and that is what the original question is asking.

Answer (score 0):

One major issue I had with `bib2gls`, is that Zotero (my reference management of choice) doesn't allow the fields and bib types it uses.

Therefore, I created a little Python package [bib2glossary](https://pypi.org/project/bib2glossary/), to convert between bib and tex, with user defined mapping of field-to-parameter names.

```
>> pip install bib2glossary
>> glossary2bib path/to/file.tex --entry-type misc --param2field path/to/file.json
>> bib2glossary path/to/file.bib --entry-type misc --param2field path/to/file.json
```

It uses [TexSoup](https://github.com/alvinwan/TexSoup) and [BibtexParser](https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.io/) to parse `bibtex` and `latex` respectively