# Glossary entries that are only referenced from other glossary entries do not end up in the document

Tags: glossaries

I’m getting dangling glossary entries. If an acronym or glossary entry is not referenced by the main document, only from other glossary entries (which *are* referenced from the main document and thus show up in the glossary chapter), they do not end up in the PDF, and `hyperref` shows they are dangling:

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{glo:foobar} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

pdfTeX warning (dest): name{glo:foo} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = blue,
    urlcolor = blue,
    citecolor = blue,
}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,style=altlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{foo}{foo}{first metasyntactic variable}

\newacronym{meow}{meow}{the sound a cat makes}

\newglossaryentry{foobar}
{
    name=foobar,
    description={combination of two metasyntactic variables,
        but also often used as \emph{fubar}}
}

\newglossaryentry{bar}
{
    name=bar,
    description={second metasyntactic variable, see also
        \gls{foo}, \gls{foobar}, \gls{baz}}
}

\newglossaryentry{baz}
{
    name=baz,
    description={third metasyntactic variable, see also
        \gls{foo}, \gls{bar}}
}

\newglossaryentry{eins}{name=eins,description={eins, siehe \gls{zwei}}}
\newglossaryentry{zwei}{name=zwei,description={zwei, siehe \gls{drei}}}
\newglossaryentry{drei}{name=drei,description={drei, siehe \gls{vier}}}
\newglossaryentry{vier}{name=vier,description={vier, siehe \gls{fynf}}}
\newglossaryentry{fynf}{name=fynf,description={fynf, siehe \gls{sechs}}}
\newglossaryentry{sechx}{name=sechs,description={sechs, siehe \gls{sieben}}}
\newglossaryentry{sieben}{name=sieben,description={sieben, siehe \gls{acht}}}
\newglossaryentry{acht}{name=acht,description={acht, und alle haben mitgemacht}}

\begin{document}

bla bla \gls{bar} bla bla \gls{baz} bla bla \gls{eins} bla bla

\newpage
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The resulting glossary chapter has only *bar* and *baz* but not those entries they refer to, even though they ought link to them. (However, *meow* should not show up.) Similarily, entries *eins* through *acht* should also show up (i.e. something that limits nesting is not acceptable; in reality, this will likely not nest *that* much, but as generation of the PDF is automated, I require a way that permits me to script this and, if looping is needed, to be able to break the loop in a deterministic fashion).

After some comments, I have added [a request](https://github.com/fracpete/latex-maven/pull/7) to the `latex-maven-plugin` to allow repeating running `makeglossaries` as a quick workaround (with limited recursion depth, of course)… for now. (The question still stays open, I cannot rely on [bib2gls](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353000/43807) or test it yet.)

Comment: Okay, I made a mistake, this macro was just to suppress the glossary link output, so this was not what you searched for, but it is mostly used to associate different glossary entries.

Comment: Hm, this works for me. After compilation and `makeglossaries` script I see all `\gls` usages expanded in the glossary

Comment: @ChristianHupfer how do you compile it? I run `pdflatex mwe.tex` then `makeglossaries mwe` then twice pdflatex again.

Comment: @mirabilos: Try this scheme `pdflatex ; makeglossaries ; pdflatex ; makeglossaries ; pdflatex`

Comment: @mirabilos: I don't know. I have to investigate that. Perhaps Nicola Talbot shows up and has a better solution for this

Comment: You have to run `makeglossaries` multiple times, I think. I tried to write a script which would automate this as it is very difficult to ensure you run it enough times, compiling the document in between, but it does not work terribly well so I can't recommend it. I keep wondering if glossaries would not be better handled using the frameworks we have for bibliographies .... Something like Biblatex/Biber but Glslatex/gliber, perhaps ;).

Comment: Is there any file (a `makeglossaries` output file perhaps) which stays deterministic, i.e. I could recognise “this file didn’t change from the last `makeglossaries` run” and abort the loop thus?

Comment: @cfr I'm guessing you missed the question [Is there a program for managing glossary tags?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342544/is-there-a-program-for-managing-glossary-tags)

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned in the comments, the problem here is that the entries in the `description` field aren't present in the document on the first LaTeX run. It's only once they are actually typeset in the glossary (*after* the glossary has been created by the indexing application) that they are actually indexed which means another call to the indexing application. There's not much that can be done about this with just `glossaries` and `makeglossaries`. You could try searching for the pattern `pdfTeX warning (dest): name{glo:`*label*`} has been referenced but does not exist` but this only appears with `hyperref`. The underlying problem (the indexing isn't complete on the first run) remains. You can also get a false match for this pattern if you've accidentally used `\glshyperlink` without indexing the entry.

There is a new command line application called [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) that can be used instead of `makeglossaries` / `makeindex` / `xindy`, and is now in both TeX Live and MikTeX. It only works with the `glossaries-extra` extension package (at least v1.12, although the latest version is best), and the glossary entries are stored in a `.bib` file instead of in a `.tex` file. So your example entries would be in a `.bib` file (called, say, `test.bib`):

```
@acronym{foo,
  short={foo},
  long={first metasyntactic variable}
}


@acronym{meow,
  short={meow},
  long={the sound a cat makes}
}

@entry{foobar,
   name={foobar},
   description={combination of two metasyntactic variables,
       but also often used as \emph{fubar}}
}

@entry{bar,
   name={bar},
   description={second metasyntactic variable, see also
       \gls{foo}, \gls{foobar}, \gls{baz}}
}

@entry{baz,
   name={baz},
   description={third metasyntactic variable, see also
        \gls{foo}, \gls{bar}}
}

@entry{eins,name={eins},description={eins, siehe \gls{zwei}}}
@entry{zwei,name={zwei},description={zwei, siehe \gls{drei}}}
@entry{drei,name={drei},description={drei, siehe \gls{vier}}}
@entry{vier,name={vier},description={vier, siehe \gls{fynf}}}
@entry{fynf,name={fynf},description={fynf, siehe \gls{sechs}}}
@entry{sechs,name={sechs},description={sechs, siehe \gls{sieben}}}
@entry{sieben,name={sieben},description={sieben, siehe \gls{acht}}}
@entry{acht,name={acht},description={acht, und alle haben mitgemacht}}
```

There's a slight difference to the document `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = blue,
    urlcolor = blue,
    citecolor = blue,
}
\usepackage[record,% <--- changed
   nonumberlist,style=altlist]
   {glossaries-extra}% <--- changed

\GlsXtrLoadResources[% <--- changed
  src={test},% data in test.bib
]

\begin{document}

bla bla \gls{bar} bla bla \gls{baz} bla bla \gls{eins} bla bla

\newpage
\printunsrtglossaries% <--- changed

\end{document}
```

Note that there's no `\makeglossaries` command. Instead the `record` option writes all the indexing information in the `.aux` file. This file is read by `bib2gls`, so it can find out which entries have been referenced. It then parses the fields for commands like `\gls` to determine dependencies. If you run `bib2gls` with `--verbose` it will list the dependencies that it's found for each entry:

```
Added dependent: foo
Added dependent: foobar
Added dependent: baz
Added dependent: barfoo
Added dependent: bar
Added dependent: zwei
Added dependent: drei
Added dependent: vier
Added dependent: fynf
Added dependent: sechs
Added dependent: sieben
Added dependent: acht
```

The default behaviour is to add the dependent entries for each referenced entry. The location list for the dependent entries won't updated until the next run (as that's something `bib2gls` can't determine), but since you've used `nonumberlist` this isn't an issue for your document.

The verbose mode also lists the entries as they're written to the external file that's loaded by `\GlsXtrLoadResources`:

```
acht
bar
barfoo
baz
drei
eins
foo
foobar
fynf
sechs
sieben
vier
zwei
```

so it's managed to pick up the dependants for the referenced entries.

Comment: Sounds very promising. Infinite loops is the problem with my script. Not always, but sometimes ...

Comment: Sounds promising, but it’s not ready yet… Debian only has glossaries-extra 1.11 ☹ But could you add a Maven build system (`pom.xml`) to the repository and remove the binary files (*.jar, possibly the PDF) (or at least move them to another branch) so I can package bib2gls for Debian eventually (once Norbert updates texlive to include the newer glossaries-extra version)?

Comment: @mirabilos I'll see if I can work out how to do that. I've not written any Maven build stuff. The latest version of `glossaries-extra` is v1.13 which I only uploaded to CTAN on 2017-02-07. v1.12 was released a few days earlier but there was an urgent bug fix (re `\glsdisp`). Hopefully it won't take long to make it into the distributions. I'm going away tomorrow for a week, but I'll try to sort stuff out when I get back. I'll move the binaries to my website to make things simpler.

Comment: OK thanks, we’ll look at it when you come back then, and I have something I can use in the meanwhile.