# Show custom commands within structures tab of TexMaker?

Tags: glossaries, texmaker, editors

I am using `\input{GlossaryEntries}` to include a list of glossary entries to my document. As this list easily gets long and therefore bad to overview, I would like to list every `\newglossaryentry{entry}{...}` in the structure tab of TexMaker. This would allow easy navigation to the entries and easy ordering once a new entry is added.

Is it possible to list custom command entries, such as above, to the structures tab of TexMaker (or another editor)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{a contrived acronym}

\newglossaryentry{computer1}
{
  name=computer1,
 description={computer1}
}

\newglossaryentry{computer2}
{
 name=computer2,
description={computer2}
}

\newglossaryentry{computer3}
{
name=computer3,
description={computer3}
}

\begin{document}

\gls{abc} 

\gls{computer3}

\end{document}
```

Now it would be awesome if "ABC", "computer1", "computer2", "computer3" was selectable in the structure tab of TexMaker.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. - 1) Do you mean something like the structure of chapter, section,... (on the left) for every glossaryentry?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. That a similar list like that of chapter / sections etc. is made for glossaryentries within a .tex file. I will try to add a MWE, even though I guess it has more to do with the capability of TexMaker / Editor than with TeX. Unless one could use e.g.  `label{...}` within the glossary entry to create a label entry for each glossary in the structure tree. But as it is in the preamble I dont think this works.

Comment: You might be interested in [`bib2gls`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/bib2gls/) which is currently still under development but should be uploaded to CTAN soon. It was developed in response to [Is there a program for managing glossary tags?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342544/is-there-a-program-for-managing-glossary-tags) The glossary entries are stored in a .bib file and can (hopefully) be managed in JabRef, making them easier to manage.