# How can I make revtex4_2 compatible custom bibliography entries with extended details in an appendix?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, natbib, revtex

I use revtex4_2 as a base for internal documents at my company. In these documents we often refer to, or make statements based upon elements of the US code of federal regulations (CFR). I want to be able to use a command similar to \cite in order to create a hyperlink that will take the reader to a list which holds all the referenced paragraphs' standard format name (for example, "10 CFR 626.4(a)(4)"). In addition to this list, which is basically a bibliography, I also want to have an appendix which includes the full expanded details of the referenced paragraphs as well as their full text (when appropriate). For example,

> ## Appendix A: US Code of Federal Regulations References
>
> #### 10 CFR 626.4(a)(4)
>
> ###### *Title 10 - Energy, Chapter II - Department of Energy 
>  Subchapter I - Sales >Regulation 
>  Part 626 - Procedures for Acquisition of Petroleum for the Strategic >Petroleum Reserve 
>  Section 4 - General Acquisition Strategy
>  Paragraph a - >Criteria for commencing acquisition, Subparagraph 4*
>
> *Current price levels for petroleum products and related commodities, the >ability to
>    minimize costs and avoid incurring
> excessive costs in acquisition, and the possible effect
>    on consumer and >market prices of any SPR acquisition;*

My first approach was to try to create a custom bibtex entry type, since I use external bib files. I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175896/79519) excellent solution, but when I tried to implement it, I discovered that the solution is incompatible with revtex due to its dependence on natbib. So I'm kinda stuck.

Question: Is there a way to do this that is compatible with revtex? Is there an alternative method of achieving what I'm going for besides custom bib entry types and all this rigamarole?

For context, I use TeXMaker, and am use the aapm and mph class options for revtex.

*Addendum: Because I know someone will wonder why I'm using revtex in the first place, its because I like the documents it produces and I don't yet have the knowledge to build a custom document class. Eventually I want to roll my own, but for now this is what we're using.*

EDIT: Here is an example of the data items I want to keep track of:

```
@Cfr{10_626_4a4,
  titlenumber    = {10},
  titlename      = {Energy},
  chapter        = {II},
  chaptername    = {Department of Energy},
  subchapter     = {I},
  subchaptername = {Sales Regulation},
  part           = {626},
  partname       = {Procedures for Acquisition of Petroleum for the Strategic Petroleum Reserve},
  subpart        = {},
  subpartname    = {},
  subject_group  = {},
  section        = {4},
  sectionname    = {General acquisition strategy.},
  paragraph      = {a},
  paragraph_name = {Criteria for commencing acquisition.},
  subparagraph   = {4},
  url            = {https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-10/chapter-II/subchapter-I/part-626#p-626.4(a)(4)},
  urldate        = {2022-11-25},
  full_text      = {Current price levels for petroleum products and related commodities, the ability to minimize costs and avoid incurring excessive costs in acquisition, and the possible effect on consumer and market prices of any SPR acquisition;},
}
```

In this example, several of the fields are optional as they are not used everywhere in the CFR.

Comment: It's not clear what format you have these things in, and what you anticipate putting into the tex source? Depending how much you want to hard-code, [`tocloft`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) or [`glossaries`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) may do the job. If you want to use [`revtex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex) then a bibliography-based solution is probably out the window.

Comment: Please see the example data I've added to the question. As for what I want to put in the tex source, I'd like it to be something like "Blah blah blah\cite{10_626_4a4}." within the actual content of the document. For creating the appendix, I'd like to create a new command along the lines of "\ReferencesAppendix" or something. I expect that will require writing some more extensive macros though. Does that make sense?

Comment: Try [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343852/106162), you should be able to use `bib2gls` and `glossaries-extra` to source items from a bib-like source independently of `bibtex`/`biber`.